# Issue with geo index in mongoAtlas

Tags: mongodb, indexing, 2d, geo, 2dsphere

I´ve migrating my last mLab application with heroku to the new MongoAtlas platform. I found some issues when trying to create geo indexes for my collections.

Here is how I used to integrate the index in the mLab tool:

```
db.OpenDataMadrid.createIndex( {“location.coordinates” : “2dsphere” } )
db.OpenDataMadrid.createIndex( {“location.coordinates” : “2d” } )
db.BuscadoresDatasets.createIndex( {“location.coordinates” : “2dsphere” } )
db.BuscadoresDatasets.createIndex( {“location.coordinates” : “2d” } )
```

And now my new geo indexes for both collections are like this:

```json
{
    “mappings”: {
        “dynamic”: true,
        “fields”: {
            “location”: {
                “fields”: {
                    “coordinates”: [
                        {
                            “dynamic”: true,
                            “type”: “document”
                        },
                        {
                            “indexShapes”: true,
                            “type”: “geo”
                        }
                    ]
                },
                “type”: “document”
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the application and the $geoquery is done I receive the following error:

```
Exception: Query failed with error code 291 and error message 'error processing query: ns=gastrorecomendador.OpenDataMadrid limit=1Tree: GEONEAR field=location.coordinates maxdist=2 isNearSphere=0

2021-10-10T07:29:36.472781+00:00 app[web.1]: Sort: {}

2021-10-10T07:29:36.472781+00:00 app[web.1]: Proj: {}

2021-10-10T07:29:36.472787+00:00 app[web.1]: planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query’ on server cluster0-shard-00-02.5ojd2.mongodb.net:27017

2021-10-10T07:29:36.585612+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception: Query failed with error code 291 and error message 'error processing query: ns=gastrorecomendador.OpenDataMadrid limit=300Tree: $and

2021-10-10T07:29:36.585620+00:00 app[web.1]: Type $eq “restaurant”

2021-10-10T07:29:36.585620+00:00 app[web.1]: Puntuacion $gt 3.5

2021-10-10T07:29:36.585621+00:00 app[web.1]: GEONEAR field=location.coordinates maxdist=250 isNearSphere=0

2021-10-10T07:29:36.585622+00:00 app[web.1]: Sort: {}

2021-10-10T07:29:36.585622+00:00 app[web.1]: Proj: {}

2021-10-10T07:29:36.585628+00:00 app[web.1]: planner returned error :: caused by :: unable to find index for $geoNear query’ on server cluster0-shard-00-02.5ojd2.mongodb.net:27017
```

Any help creating 2d and 2dphere indexes?

I’ve also try to create the index to the location variable instead of `location.coordinates` but it doesn’t work either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: Hi, the data of an object is like this:  
_id
:
5adcc9a162c88a02b8515d8c
Reference
:
"Yelp"
Name
:
"De la Vega"
Address
:
"Parque del Arroyo de la Vega"
ZipCode
:
"Arroyo de la Vega, Madrid"
Phone
:
""
Category
:
"Asadores"
Reviews
:
2
Price
:
"€€€€"
Type
:
"restaurant"
location
:
Object
type
:
"Point"
coordinates
:
Array
0
:
-3.6264837
1
:
40.5388232
Rating
:
3